# How to enable Assembly Language support in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2013

I have been searching around and everyone provides just a simple answer

> Right-click the project, Custom Build Rules, tick "Microsoft Macro Assembler".

But sadly, In 2013 its not the same. Here is the screenshot [image]

I don't know how to enable Assembly Language; by enabling Microsoft Macro Assembler. Any guidance?

I have tried all of these settings and there is no such thing as the MASM in any option tab.

Comment: Check this tutorial : http://kipirvine.com/asm/gettingStartedVS2012/index.htm

Comment: Also can't get to show up in my copy of Visual Studio 2013. Followed the updated Kip Irvine instructions for 2013 and still didn't work. What's weird is if I open the solution projects that contain assembly code from the code provided here http://www.apress.com/9781484200650 it does show up!

Comment: Don't know if this is a VS 2013 Update 4 bug but I finally got it to work by making sure to check empty project when starting with a C++ Win32 Console Application for the project type. If there are any source files at all present when you start the options for the Assembler won't show up! Then in the tree control, select Configuration Properties | Microsoft Macro Assembler | Advanced.Click on Use Safe Exception Handlers. Then select Yes (/safeseh) for Use Safe Exception Handlers. (This switch enables MASM to generate object modules that are compatible with the C++ compiler and linker.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Right-click the project, not the solution.  Then Build Dependencies + Build Customizations.  You get the dialog, tick "masm".

Comment: Just one thing please, Where can I find `project`?

Comment: The project node is the one below the one you clicked.  Shown in **bold** type in your screenshot, ConsoleApplication1.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this will useful:

- Right-click on the `file_name.asm` (in Solution Explorer)
- `Properties` -> `Configuration Properties` -> `General` -> `Item Type`
- Choose `Microsoft Macro Assembler`

Answer (score 5):

Go to **Project** (you'll find it in the top menu) > **Build Customizations...**

And check the **masm** option.

Further, in some cases (like when working with x64), the linker might have some problems finding main. To solve that, you need to manually create an entry point by:

1. going to **Project** > **Properties** : [a dialog opens]
2. in the dialog, select "**Configuration Properties**" > "**Linker**" > "**Advanced**"
3. There you'll find a field called "**Entry Point**". If it is blank, open its drop down menu and select edit.
4. write "main" and click ok, and ok once again on the main dialog.

It should work fine after this

Answer (score 1):

I had to right-click the .asm file first.  MASM appeared in this context menu.  After doing this, it appeared in the project's context menu as well.  Seems like a issue with VS2015.  Also, I am working on Windows 10 64-bit.

In order to get the 64-bit versions to compile, I had to set the Entry Point option for the linker to main and I also had to set the `LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO` option as well.

This option can be found in VS2013 Pro under

> Configuration Properties->Linker->System->Enable Large Addresses

Choose "**No**" in the drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I sorted this problem like this

> choose tools > toolbox items > .NET framework components then select Assembly installer (VS C++ 2005 express)