# Assembly language compilation in Visual Studio 13

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2013, masm

I have an assembly language code in notepad file. I heard it can be compiled without installing MASM exclusively. I've searched for that and I found out that Visual Studio can compile it. I have Visual Studio 13, Kindly guide me what would I have to do to do so.

Comment: You will find that having your "assembly" code processed by VS13 as a VS13 project, will allow you to easily use VS13's debugger on your assembled code.    Are you sure you want to "compile" it using just raw MASM?

Comment: Yes, that'd be great. I just dont want to link and debug through DOS every time

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable Assembly Language support in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078021/how-to-enable-assembly-language-support-in-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio includes masm or actually `ml.exe`, which is the actual name of microsoft's assembler since version 6.11, which goes back to the days of msdos 6.22. For 64 bit mode, use `ml64.exe`.

To create a project:

- create a folder to hold the project.
- Create the project specifying the folder name as the project name, do not check create directories.
- Choose win32 console application when the choice appears.
- Click on next when it appears and click on empty project. This should open up the project window.
- Right click on the project name ... all configurations ... characters ... and change from `unicode` to `not set` if you don't want unicode.
- Click on project in the menu and add the `.asm` file name, such as `example.asm`.
- Then right click on `example.asm`, properties, item type , and select `custom build tool`.
- Then click on custom build tool.

  - For debug build:

    - command line: `ml /Zi /c /Fo$(outdir)\example.obj example.asm`
    - outputs: `$(outdir)\example.obj`
  - For release build:

    - command line: `ml /c /Fo$(outdir)\example.obj example.asm`
    - outputs: `$(outdir)\example.obj`

Comment: The process gives the error
 "'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file." for four files

Comment: If you just want to use ml.exe, then click on programs / visual studio / tools / visual studio .... command prompt. Then go to the project directory and use the command lines: ml /c /coff example.asm  | link example.obj (or use ml64 if creating a 64 bit program, but I don't know if the link command will be differen).

Comment: as for the error, what four files are you getting this error for? Are you trying to assemble for debug mode or for release mode and is this a 32 bit or 64 bit program?

Comment: VS2013 includes ml.exe and ml64.exe, but you need to specify a custom build step to invoke the assembler. I updated my answer to explain how this is done.

Comment: I did not find ml64.exe and installing WDK did not do the trick. Do you have any idea how I could get it?

Comment: If you installed on a 64 bit OS, 64 bit builds should be enabled, and ml64.exe should be here: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio ... \ VC \ bin \ x86_amd64 \ ml64.exe .