# Visual Studio 2012: Using MASM x64 in DLL Project

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, masm

Alright, so I have a console project written in C++. I need a GUI, and I don't want to mess with any of the GUI libraries available, so I'm turning to C#.

The app does a lot of low level stuff, including some assembly code, and since x64 doesn't support inline assembly, I was using MASM. So I can't reasonably port the code over, so I make the C++ app a DLL project.

When I go to enable MASM, I check the 'masm' box in "Build Customizations". Afterwards, the expected Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Microsoft Macro Assembler menu option doesn't appear!

When compiling, I get 'unresolved external symbol *X*' where X is a label I wrote into the .asm file.

I looked into exporting a function from the original binary, but it looks like you need to build your whole export table... I'd rather not.

So, in short, how do I compile ASM into a 64-bit Windows DLL?
Maybe there's a better way I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this question, though I did not ask it very well, to be a duplicate of:

[How to enable Assembly Language support in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078021/how-to-enable-assembly-language-support-in-visual-studio-2013)

Though, the selected answer there did not fix my problem. ilovecpp's answer was the trick:

> Maybe this will useful:
>
> Right-click on the file_name.asm (in Solution Explorer)
> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Item Type
> Choose Microsoft Macro Assembler

Once that was enabled, everything compiled just fine. You can compile MASM into a DLL, just takes an extra step.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile your assembly code into a static library, and then create a native C++ DLL that will export functions from the assembly library.