# pc asm book trying to compile first asm app

Tags: windows, visual-studio, assembly, x86, nasm

I can't compile first asm exe
    i have MSVC 2005 & 2015
    i execute

```
nasm -f win32 first.asm (ok)
cl first.obj driver.c asm_io.obj (cl not found i set path enviro,
```

second attempt -> many obj files not found i found it and copy to
    source folder, 
third attempt ->

```
asm_io.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _scanf

asm_io.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _printf

)
```

using djgpp can't understand what i need to download
downloaded mingw and there is no gcc exe

Comment: http://drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/

Comment: Please add some formatting or something. I can't make heads or tails of the blob of text there.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. You say you have MSVC 2005 and 2015, then you show us nasm and at the end djgpp seems to come out of nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

MSVC does not come with the NASM assembler. You'll need to [download that separately](http://www.nasm.us/), if you do not already have it installed.

MSVC does, however, come with the MASM assembler. You can find steps on how to set it up to work with the IDE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078021/how-to-enable-assembly-language-support-in-visual-studio-2013). The problem is, NASM and MASM are not perfectly compatible, syntax-wise. Someone who knows assembly could translate between them trivially, but you will probably have difficulty learning from a book that uses different syntax than your assembler accepts.

Aside from that, I am not sure why you are trying to *compile* the code after you have *assembled* it. That is not necessary, and actually won't do anything useful. `nasm` is an assembler; you run it to assemble assembly code. `cl` is a C and C++ compiler; you run it to compile `c` and `cpp` files. You never need to use `cl` or `gcc` when you are writing assembly.

Comment: Almost correct, but cl.exe is both a compiler and linker. You can use it to link the assembler's output.

Comment: @IInspectable I wouldn't say that it is a linker, but rather that it can *invoke* the linker after it has finished compiling. In fact, it does, unless the `/c` flag is specified. cl.exe is just a front-end driver for the compiler. If you just want to link assembled code, you would call the linker (link.exe) directly.

Comment: You are right, that was sloppily put. The official wording on [Compiler Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s7c9wdw.aspx) is: *"cl.exe is a tool that controls the Microsoft C and C++ compilers and linker."* Still, though, it is common practice to use cl.exe even if just for linking.