# Why is 'cmp' not necessary when using jumps on a loop?

Tags: assembly, x86

I fill `ecx` with the amount of times I want to loop, `dec`rease `ecx` and `jump if not zero` to `back:`.

Now the question is, why isn't:

`cmp ecx, 0`
necessary before `jnz back`.
How does `jnz` knows automatically which register to compare when doing the jump? (which is `ecx` in this case).

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a = 0;

    __asm 
    {
        mov eax, 0
        mov ecx, 4
back:
        inc eax
        sub ecx, 1
        jnz back
        mov a, eax
    }

    cout << a << endl; //outputs '4' properly

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `jnz` doesn't compare anything it just checks the zero flag bit. It doesn't care how that flag got set, and `sub ecx, 1` sets it too not just `cmp`. Check out the instruction set reference to see how instructions affect flags. Also you might want to read the basic architecture manual.

Comment: ok, post it as an answer and I'll accept it. If you have any links, that'd be great too!

Comment: If you are trying to learn assembly language, you *really* shouldn't be using inline assembly. You can [configure Visual Studio to run MASM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078021/how-to-enable-assembly-language-support-in-visual-studio-2013), so that you can assemble an ASM file directly. That way, you don't have to leave the IDE, but you won't be writing in C++ anymore.

Comment: @CodyGray, yes I'm learning, thank you for taking the time to give me advice and help me out! -edit. oh I remember I started using inline assembly because I read that it is very difficult to output the value of a variable thru asm

Comment: Well, you would have to link to the C runtime library so that you can call the `printf` function. It isn't really that difficult, and it's actually a good exercise because it requires you to understand how to call functions. (Or, if you're using MASM, you can use the `INVOKE` pseudo-opcode, which will do a lot of the dirty work for you. But really, you should learn how to make function calls with both standard Windows calling conventions, `__cdecl` and `__stdcall`.) Otherwise, if you're just printing values for debugging purposes, you can use the VS debugger, which is fantastic.

Comment: You could replace | sub ecx,1 | jnz back | with | loop back |.

Comment: @rcgldr, I know, I only used this example for my question. sub ecx, 1 jnz back, runs faster btw.

Comment: @CodyGray - VS2015 inlines printf (not sure if this is just 64 bit mode or both 32 bit and 64 bit mode), with a complicated mess of code. I don't know how to disable this. I now use a small print function with a fixed number of parameters in a C source file, and call it from the assembly code as needed.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about changes made by the [UCRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/), @rcgldr, so that would be true for all builds. `printf` isn't exactly inlined. The C++ compiler still emits a `call printf` instruction. The difference is that `printf` is now defined in a header file (`<Program Files>\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt\stdio.h`), and thus gets compiled directly into your object file as a stub that essentially forwards to `__stdio_common_vfprintf`. But you're right, this may complicate calling it from an ASM module.

Comment: @CodyGray - I meant that the printf function effectively gets inlined, not the call to printf. Try outputting assembly code from a C source file with a call to printf and you'll see the *mess* that I'm commenting about. With the C source file included in a project, I can call printf from the assembly code, but I haven't checked to see if the number of parameters is an issue.

Comment: While learning you don't need to print anything in early stages. Just use breakpoints and debugger to check values in registers/memory. Later you will figure out how to call printf-like functions from clib, or even create your own. You may also call your assembly function from C with some target pointers like `{ int x; asmfunction(&x); printf("%d\n", x); }` and in assembly only load the pointer argument, and put result value into that memory. Using inline assembly will probably soon lead to more confusion than learning some basic API/ABI things to make ASM<->C calling working.

Comment: [Does a JE must follow directly to an CMP?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/4436/2563)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In assembly, there is more than one instruction that can be used to perform a "comparison".

In general (with only a very few exceptions), conditional branching instructions do not compare any registers at all. They test the so-called "status flags" (zero-flag, carry-flag, etc.) in the `EFLAGS` register, and determine whether or not to perform the jump based on the status of these flags.

As you can see [in this list](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html), some instructions even have multiple names. For example, `je` (*J*ump if *E*qual) is just an alias for `jz` (*J*ump if *Z*ero flag is set).

As for the `cmp` instruction, it is simply a subtraction. It sets the flags as if a subtraction had been performed, but does not save the value or modify any of its operands. For example, if you subtract 10 from 12 (either via `cmp` or `sub`), the zero flag is cleared (since the result is not zero) and the carry flag is cleared (there was no need to borrow). In this case, based on the status of the zero flag, a `jnz` (aka `jne`) will take the branch, while a `jz` (aka `je`) will not.

Almost all arithmetic and bitwise instructions influence these flags, as well as some others. The official documentation makes it very clear which flags are affected by each instruction. For example, `dec cx` also sets the flags. If the value in `cx` is zero after it has been decremented, then the zero flag will be set. Thus, `jnz` will not jump and you will fall out of the loop.

Comment: *"branches do not compare any registers"* `jcxz/jecxz` being exception of course (it *does* check value of register ... and it doesn't check any flag register value). (x86 has some exception for almost every generic enough "assembly rule") ... and flags themselves are stored in flag register, so other branches do check bits in that register. Yet I don't suggest any changes to your answer, I find it correct as is, it's just that "x86" thing that there's always more to it. :)

Comment: @Ped7g esp on x86, there's always an exception to the rule, but I didn't want to make it even more confusing to the OP than it already was (obviously) :) But you're right, perhaps it could have been mentioned